# Is it possible for a WCF Async call method to fail?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

As far as I know, it's not good practice to use them when there's application specific error handling available.

I'm calling a method from a WCF service like so:

```
Service.Login += new EventHandler<LoginCompletedEventArgs>(LoginCompleted);
Service.LoginAsync(username, password);
```

In the resulting 'LoginCompleted' method I can use the following to check for errors:

```
if (e.Error == null)
```

As errors can be analysed once the method has completed, is it still necessary to place try-catch blocks around the 'LoginAsync' call? In other words, can *anything* go wrong with the 'LoginAsync' call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Things can go wrong with the call itself... for example, say your network goes down and you can't actually complete the call. The try/catch would be useful for those situations. Handling the exceptions that occurred during the asynchronous operation is being done exactly how you should be doing it.

Basically, if you want to handle any exceptions in making the call, use the try/catch. If you want to handle any exceptions during the asynchronous operation, use the `e.Error` as you have been.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what could happen, but some scenarios jump to my head: out threads in the pool, out of memory...I would think that it is **not** necessary.

Comment: If those things were to happen though, any ideas which section of code would pick them up?

Comment: I would think these kind of things are the ones that should handle at the last line of defense: that could be a try/catch in the main method or something like this because I think this a very edged case. =)